# To create or not to create model for images

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I am making an application that will be loading few images and will be displaying them on HTML(current not using any frameworks like Angular or KO or Backbone)

Each image will be a tile on the page, so it will be a collection of tiles on the web page.

For making the app maintainable I have started implementing MVC pattern.

I have started by making 1 Model(container for data of tiles) and 1 View(showing the changes of model) and one Global Controller for the link between app and user.

My question is that since each tile will be showing some data and their behavior on click will be different(for example - If user clicks on one tile and then clicks on the other tile then I need to perform some manipulation). Will it be good/best idea to further break down view into tile-view and mode into tile-model?

I am using Observer Pattern for interaction between model, view and controller using native js.

Answer (score 1):

As I've implemented recently a composite model of forms with controls, both implemented as MVC, I can say that it is completely OK to use MVC "components" within the the MVC "host". What you probably will need to have is a tiny loader that bounds models of the nestsed components with their controls and views. The main idea of my MVC approach is described here: http://alexatnet.com/articles/model-view-controller-mvc-javascript